# Surefire: don't create /tmp/stdout*deferred

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, surefire

Since [SUREFIRE-938](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-938) the output of test is buffered in /tmp/stdout*deferred in order to create XML report. I am not interested in the report in XML or any other form, but I gather gigabytes of logs during the test executions, and write them to /tmp, too. Sometimes the total size of both buffer file and the output log is too big and it won't fit - is there a way to disable the report and all this buffering (which slows down the test as well)?

Comment: Reading the code, I initially thought the [`disableXmlReport`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#disableXmlReport) would work... but then I found [SUREFIRE-1147](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1147) (unresolved) and it appears it still creates lots of memory usage, even with this parameter set to `false`.